# Responsive Image with correct aspect ratio in Flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I cannot seem to achieve a responsive image inside a flex-box item correctly. If the image is one of the flex-box item, it works well ([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/10/))

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.parent input {
  flex: 1;
}
.parent input:focus + img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/40/000000/graduation-cap.png">
<input />
<img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/40/00000/user.png">
</div>
```

### When the image is inside a flex item, it starts to misbehave.

Scenario 1: Image stretches distorting the aspect ratio ([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/17/))

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.parent input {
  flex: 1;
}
.parent input:focus + div {
  display: none;
}
.parent img {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.parent .funny {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/40/000000/graduation-cap.png">
<input />
<div class="funny">
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OX10v8tUiCY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADE8/QcezYUDPvxU/s96-c/photo.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Scenario 2: Image leaves empty space ([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/22/))

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}
.parent input {
  flex: 1;
}
.parent input:focus + div {
  display: none;
}
.parent img {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.parent .funny {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/40/000000/graduation-cap.png">
<input />
<div class="funny">
<div>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OX10v8tUiCY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADE8/QcezYUDPvxU/s96-c/photo.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Scenario 3: The layout is good until the input receives  focus, then verything breaks: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/74/)

This happens in IE 11, Chrome (Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)), but haven't tested in Firefox and Edge.

### Is there something i haven't studied about Flex-box, or is it a bug?

Comment: Images don't react as you might expect a flex-children...try wrapping them in a div.

Comment: @Paulie_D i have, see http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/22/

Comment: Look here - http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/74/ I know it's not a good solution. I have no idea why the browser acts like that. If you tweak the display of the image after the content is loaded, it's getting fixed. Probably a bug?

Comment: @EliyaCohen thanks, thanks, a lot... you ave created the exact error am receiving... the layout starts well until you click the input, then everything breaks...

Answer (score 1):

The below code seems to be working fine for me.
I've just set the image height and width in your first example.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.parent input {
  flex: 1;
}
.parent input:focus + img {
  display: none;
}

img {
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/40/000000/graduation-cap.png">
<input />
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OX10v8tUiCY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADE8/QcezYUDPvxU/s96-c/photo.jpg">
</div>
```

For the second example that you shared, again just setting the img height to 40px instead of making it as 100% seems to be working for me. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/95/)

Same with scenario 3. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/100/)

Comment: the first example i shared was working fine, it was meant to show the different between the working and the not working code. the second example is clever, but i don't want to have to set a fixed image size as that is not responsive to the parent. the third example works the same as mine

Comment: My mistake. I've edited the fiddle link to the third example. I guess you would be setting some height to the parent and giving the same height in px to the img should not affect the responsiveness. This probably has to do with how the browser tries to manipulate the width auto with height in percentage inside a nested flex layout.

Answer (score 0):

You have added only one image in `<div>`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dggupta25/ohLc5xyw/62/)

Comment: the link you sent has the last image leaving a lot of empty pace on the right with is also something i highlighted in the question (third example ~ http://jsfiddle.net/ohLc5xyw/22/)

Comment: Something weird I have encountered - If you refresh the page, you'll see you leave a blank space. if you open your inspector, and the toggle the display, the space will be fixed.

Comment: @EliyaCohen that's the behaviors. the examples i provided are the simplified scenarios of what am observing...

Comment: @EliyaCohen Yes, I am also experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Please don't link to an answer, if you have code you'd like to share, please put it in the question itself, not on an external site.